# How to convert a column in a data frame to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe

So I'm working in this table:

| Raumeinheit | Langzeitarbeitslose |
| --- | --- |
| Hamburg | 33,23 |
| Berlin | 44,56 |

I'm trying to calculate the mean of Langzeitarbeitslose but I can't because

```
is.numeric
```

comes out as false because the column Langzeitarbeitslose is defined as character.

I think this might be because here in Germany we use "," to show decimals and not "."

I already tried

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose))
```

that gave me a working table in the console preview but when I looked at the table with

```
view(West_Data)
```

It still showed the Decimals of Langzeitarbeitslose seperated with ',' and

```
is.numeric(West_Data$Langzeitarbeitslose)
```

came back as false.

Comment: How did you import that data? Using read.table you can set decimals to comma: `dec = ","`.

Comment: @zx8754 I imported it with the `read.csv` command. Is there a way to define decimals to comma with my full table already read in?

Comment: We need to update the column: `West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose))`

Comment: Try it again with `read.csv("myfile.csv", dec = ",")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to assign the result of `as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose))` to the column `West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose`

```
West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose))
```

The result of `print(West_data)` will be:

```
  Raumeinheit Langzeitarbeitslose
1     Hamburg               33.23
2      Berlin               44.56
```

The cast of datatype can be checked here:

```
> str(West_data)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Raumeinheit        : chr  "Hamburg" "Berlin"
 $ Langzeitarbeitslose: num  33.2 44.6
```

Comment: worked. I didn't know I had to adress the column as an object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the type conversion back to your dataframe?

using `tidyverse`

```
# reproducible data using dput()
df <- structure(list(Raumeinheit = c("Hamburg", "Berlin"), Langzeitarbeitslose = c("33,23", 
"44,56")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df <- df %>% 
         mutate(Langzeitarbeitslose = 
          as.numeric(gsub(",", ".",Langzeitarbeitslose)))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Raumeinheit Langzeitarbeitslose
  <chr>                     <dbl>
1 Hamburg                    33.2
2 Berlin                     44.6
```